QuickFixN: LOGON implementation issue and authentication
Version FIX50SP2.
In quickfix repo, there are messages for both FIX50SP2 and FIXT11:
https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/tree/master/Messages

In docs, I couldn't find even the vaguest notion regarding which one I need to choose to implement FIX client LOGON for version FIX50SP2.
Am I supposed to send Logon messages explicitly or I need to implement authentication in ToAdmin method?

This is the current snippet to intercept ToAdmin so that to add credentials:
    public void ToAdmin(QuickFix.Message message, SessionID sessionId)
    {
        // Customize admin messages before sending

        string msgType = message.Header.GetString(Tags.MsgType);

        if (msgType == MsgType.LOGON)
        {
            // Coinbase-specific fields
            string apiKey = _settings.Get(sessionId).GetString("SenderCompID"); // API Key
            string secret = _settings.Get(sessionId).GetString("Secret"); // API Secret
            string passphrase = _settings.Get(sessionId).GetString("Passphrase"); // API Passphrase

Implementing this API: https://docs.cdp.coinbase.com/exchange/docs/fix-msg-order-entry-50#logon-35a

I'm not sure what docs you read, but you are going about this quite wrong.
Creating and sending a message should look somewhat similar this, which I'm copy/pasting right from the web site docs.
FIX44.NewOrderSingle order = new FIX44.NewOrderSingle(
    new ClOrdID("1234"),
    new Symbol("AAPL"),
    new Side(Side.BUY),
    new TransactTime(DateTime.Now),
    new OrdType(OrdType.MARKET));

// add optional fields here if needed

Session.SendToTarget(order, sessionID);

You will be using FIX50SP2 instead of FIX44.
In FIX5, the consortium split "admin" messages (logon, logout, heartbeat, etc.) into their own dictionary, and that's what FIXT11 is.  You probably won't be creating those messages manually.
ToAdmin is for intercepting outgoing admin messages before they go out to the counterparty, in case you need to tweak them.  Most often it's used to inject username/password fields into logon messages.  I don't know what you are attempting to do, but it looks like it's based on a misunderstanding.
Have you looked at the QF/n examples?  I highly recommend running the TradeClient and Executor against each other in different terminals, and then checking out the code.

Thanks, Grant. My issues is only with Logon message. Any other messages I do send the way you described. The problem is 1) I can't connect 2) I don't know how to properly configure the client to use Username, Passphrase, signature. I override ToAdmin message but either configuration wrong or I don't get Logon message FromAdmin

Do I need to explicitly use Dictionaries in CFG file?

is it correct to intercept ToAdmin to add credentials to logon message?

Ah, sorry.  I think I maybe misread your question and misdiagnosed the problem.
(1) Yes, it is correct to use ToAdmin in this way.  (2) Yes, you always need a DD.  For FIX5, you need AppDataDictionary=path/to/FIX50SP2.xml and TransportDataDictionary=path/to/FIXT11.xml in your config. (3) Use a LogFileFactory - this log should be your only source of truth for what is being sent and received (don't rely on Console.WriteLine statements!).

Amazing, thank you very much

FYI, you'll probably need to customize your FIX50SP2.xml file.  I've never met a counterparty who doesn't make their own custom changes to messages/fields, and your file needs to match.  They should have documentation.

Actually, yes, the counterparty has their dictionary file and after I started using the dictionary, I started having error: "QuickFix.DictionaryParseException: invalid type: LONG"

Is LONG used as a <field> type in their dictionary?  That's not a valid FIX datatype.  They should be using something from this list.  You should replace LONG with something appropriate, likely "INT" in most cases.

Indeed, they have it: <field name='RptSeq' number='83' type='LONG'/> and this is the official coinbase documentation. That's strange. Do I have to update it anyway?

Yes, changed to INT and now another error: Timed out waiting for logon response

I can't diagnose that with what you've given. Check your FIX logs (you're using a FileLogFactory, right? Do you see a 35=3 or 35=j reject response?

I created test and during this test I successfully login and logout using initiator.Stop(); but when I start the test again next time I get 58=INVALID_SIGNATURE and 35=5 == reject. I guess, the session is reused but not sure how to fix it yet. And yes, I deleted session files and it worked.
Do I need session at all? Reset*** settings set to Y helped to solve this issue
